# How to find an area between $x =\frac 12$ on the right, $y = \frac x{\sqrt3}$ above and by the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 2x$ with polar coordinates?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

The problem is: Find the area of the region that is bounded by $x =\frac 12$ on the right and $y = \frac x{\sqrt3}$ above, and by the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 2x$.

I have a general idea of how to find the bounds of the radius and angles, but I'm not entirely sure. As of right now, I calculated that the radius bounds were $0$ to $2\cos(\theta)$ and the theta bounds are $\frac{5π}3$ to $\frac{π}6.$ Am I going in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: Ok. Isabella's integral made me rethink it. Now I have the feeling that the intended region is, indeed, below the line $y=x/\sqrt3$, above **the bottom half** of that circle, and to the left of the line $x=1/2$. I would still split the region into a triangle and a thin segment of a circle. The latter has $\phi\in[-\pi/2,-\pi/3]$.

Comment: So scratch my two first comments and the first pic that only showed the first quadrant when we have action in the fourth quadrant as well. A new pic matches the wording better I think. If you think it's still wrong, then you can just edit it out :-)

Comment: I just became a fortune-teller. My Vector Calculus students will battle this as an extra exercise next week when preparing for their exam. And I get some use of the picture!

Comment: Why did you change the question? The picture is now totally unrelated. And the new version doesn't make any sense because this new circle doesn't even touch the line $x=2$.

Comment: Please don't edit the question such that the answers will lose meaning after the edit

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate $$\displaystyle\int_0^{1/2}\int_{-\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}}^{\frac{x}{\sqrt3}}dydx$$ to find the area of the region.

Notice that there's no need to use polar coordinates.

Comment: yes, you're right

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes, I confused.. I edit it, thanks!

Comment: Anyway, your bounds made me see the light. We use the BOTTOM half of the circle. So my first comment is misguided. +1 for figuring out the need to use the lower semicircle. I will delete the first comment, and replace the second to reflect this change.

Comment: You are right in that there is no absolute need to use polar coordinates. It is just that some of us find it easier to calculate integrals like
$$\int_{\phi=-\pi/2}^{-\pi/3}\int_{r=0}^{2\cos\phi}r\,dr\,d\phi$$
as opposed to having to deal with those square roots. A matter of taste, of course. And it is good to know how to calculate it both ways!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok :P

Answer (score 0):

With polar coordinates you can not solve it with one integral.

You need to connect the origin to the point on the circle where the circle and the line $x=1/2$ intersect.

For the bottom part  your $\theta$ goes from $\pi /6$ to $\pi /3$, while your $r$ goes from $0$ to $(\sec \theta )/2$

For the upper part your $\theta$ goes from $\pi/3 $ to $\pi/2$, while your $r$ goes from $0$ to $2\cos \theta$

Good Luck

Comment: Hmm. I think Isabella is onto something. The picture (and the region we are both apparently thinking about) doesn't quite match the wording. I will edit the pic. You may want to rethink this as well. I apologize for the trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Hopefully the new region is easier in polar coordinate to describe.

Comment: I think the shaded region of the freshly edited pic matches the wording. I'm afraid it's not too simple to describe using polar coordinates. What do you think, is this the intended one?

Comment: This one is as complicated as the first one You still need to do two polar integrals. One part for the circular boundary and one for the vertical line boundary.

Comment: I guess that is the intention of the problem designer. Of course, we can skip integrals altogether when handling the triangular part.

Comment: That is correct, we can find the triangular part without integration.